# Timeout when making HTTPS requests in Android Emulator

Tags: android, parse-platform, proxy, timeout, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make HTTPS request using the HttpURLConnection class. When the URL starts with "http://" the connection responds as expected after calling .connect(). The problem is when the URL starts with "http**s**://", the connection always times out (after 5000ms, the timeout I set). The exception message is:

> failed to connect to [url] (port [XXX]) after 5000ms

I'm using the Parse SDK for Android and every query I make times out as well. The exception message is:

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

and

> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /54.84.111.80:443 timed out".

So I think the Parse SDK always uses HTTPs behind the hood.

Some things I think I need to point out:

- I'm using the emulator with the Android 5.1.1 x86_64.
- The internet I'm using has a proxy and the emulator is being started with the `-http-proxy` command line option.
- I can't deactivate this proxy because I'm using the internet of the company I work for.
- I have an application written in .NET that uses the Parse SDK as well, and it runs fine using the same internet connection.

Comment: the address you are hitting , can it be accessible from pc

Comment: @ghosttalker In my case, I'm making requests to the youtube.com. It works fine when I access it from the browser. I can't seem to access the address that parse gives me in the exception message (54.84.111.80). When I try to access it from the browser, a page appears telling me that my connection is not private and that I should not continue (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID). I think this is probably the proxy getting in the way.

Comment: can you please share your log file

Comment: @ghosttalker where do I get this?

Answer (score -2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

try using this tag instead of

```
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```

if the problem still persists then it could be proxy problem

Comment: @Selvin I am telling him to recheck, so Keep your comments away if you do not have solution